# Тма, мна, оксія у "Гайдамаках" Т. Шевченка

Tags: значення-слів, невідоме-слово

Такі рядки:

> Йдете в люди, а там тепер
>
> Все письменне стало.
>
> Вибачайте, що не вивчив,
>
> Бо й мене хоч били,
>
> Добре били, а багато
>
> Дечому навчили!
>
> **Тма, мна знаю, а оксію**
>
> Не втну таки й досі.

В тлумачному словнику ані "тми, мни", ані оксії не знаходжу.

Треба пошукати в якихось більш спеціалізованих джерелах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

З книги "[Кобзар. Вперше зі щоденником автора](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=YIOVAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT1009&lpg=PT1009&dq=%22%D0%A2%D0%BC%D0%B0,%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%22%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&source=bl&ots=o4uVRbB6FV&sig=DSssHhH6lrzHAQfLi3ZMduo5LzE&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimz8TXrv7bAhUlQZoKHTqrDHEQ6AEIODAD#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%A2%D0%BC%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%22%20&f=false)":

> **Тма, мна** - **склади у церковнослов'янських букварях**, за якими навчали грамоти.

[СЛОВО ТАРАСА ШЕВЧЕНКА В ІСТОРІЇ ЛІТЕРАТУРНОЇ МОВИ](http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/111591/03-Gnatyuk.pdf?sequence=1). Стаття Лідії Гнатюк:

> Церковнослов’янську грамоту засвоїв Шевченко ще в дитинстві; про це
>   він згадував у «Гайдамаках»: ... Бо й мене хоч били,/ Добре били, а
>   багато/ Дечому навчили! Тма, мна знаю, а оксію/ Не втну таки й
>   досі. Відомо, що **«тма», «мна»** – це **склади в церковнослов’янських**
>   **букварях**, за якими навчали читати, а **оксі́я – діакритичний  знак,**
>   який традиційно ставився у церковнослов’янських словах.